# Confused by openssl make

Tags: compiling, openssl, version

I need to generate the `libssl*` and `libcrypto*` binaries for use on a different system. I wrote a trivial script doing it

```
#!/bin/bash

set -evx

OPENSSL_VERSION="1.0.2l"
TARGET=openssl-linux64

/bin/rm -fr $TARGET
curl -O -L http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz
mv openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION $TARGET
cd $TARGET
./Configure linux-x86_64 -shared
make
```

Everything seems to work, in the end I get the two libraries. Unfortunately, they're called `libssl.so.1.0.0` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`. I'm rather confused...

*Is it just a chaotic versioning or what's going on?*

*How can I find out what exactly was produced? Should I trust it?*

In case it matters: My system is "Linux 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon x86_64 GNU/Linux".

Comment: The `1.0.2l` is the version of the OpenSSL distribution while `1.0.0` is the shared library version. I'm not sure I understand what's strange about this. There's no reason to bump the shared library version if the API has not changed.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've seen a couple of systems (Mint or Fedora; I can't recall) having `1.0.2l` or alike installed, while there was no `1.0.0` there. I'm pretty sure about that as our program trying to load `1.0.0` found nothing at all. Pretty confusing, isn't it?

Comment: The API versions went from `0.9.8` to `1.0.0` to `1.1.0` (the most recent version), there was never a `1.0.2` API and letters are not used on shared libraries.

Comment: I'm not saying that it was the *API version*. However, I've just downloaded `openssl-1.0.2o.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, the libraries will have version 1.0.0 even though the software package will have version 1.0.2l. That's because all versions 1.0.x of the software implement the same API (same functions with the same function signatures/prototypes), so the libraries should be versioned the same since users of those libraries can use these versions interchangeably.

The version of the libraries is defined [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2l/crypto/opensslv.h#L91) in the source tree. There's a comment just above that define that explains it a little bit further.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: See also https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Versioning and https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html

Comment: I don't understand why they're doing it, when symlinking `libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.0 -> libssl.so.1.0.2l` would work equally well and keep the information about the real version. Anyway, I understand that I can use the files, thank you.

Comment: @maaartinus You're still confusing the version of the OpenSSL distribution with the shared library version. There is no 1.0.2l OpenSSL API. 1.0.0 is "the real shared library version".